# Inverse binary thresholding function on images

Tags: javascript, image

I am currently working on a sneaker recommendation application. As part of the implementation, a user needs to upload an image of a sneaker, and from this, the application attempts to find 3 closest matching shoes. To date, I have created a dataset of sneakers and have decided to use [resemblejs](https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) in order to compare the upload images against what is in the dataset.

However I am encountering a problem. Prior to sending the uploaded sneaker image, I need to ascertain it's shape in order to determine whether or not it valid for submission.

Ideally I would like all the pictures facing one way... so consider the following scenario.

User uploads:

[image]

It's in the wrong direction, so the application knows to mirror it as all images in the dataset face this direction:

[image]

[image]

So all that needs to be done is mirror the picture as it is perfectly valid. Once this is done, the image has passed preprocessing and is compared against what is in the database.

[image]

I have researched various ways of doing this, and one of the approaches that struck me involves using a inverse binary thresholding approach in order to turn the background of the image black while whiting out the contents of the shoe itself.

[image]

Is it possible to accomplish this in Javascript? If so how?

I then thought that it would make sense to analyse the picture to see which side had more black/white (dividing it in half) in order to see if it needed to be mirrored. In a case where it cannot be mirrored, the user just has to upload a new picture.

Comment: loop through the rgba, changing anything above n (ex 128) to 255 and below to 0. [this 10-year old app](http://danml.com/pub/photo2.htm) no longer boots, but the source on line 1588 gives a working ntsc B+W example. if you had a desaturated image already, you can do less math in the thresholding

Comment: Resemble.js was built for looking for pixel-level changes in screenshots websites, not actual photographs. It won't give you any useful information. Without some information about what sort of pictures users will be uploading (i.e. crappy ones they took with their phone camera or perfect profiles of sneakers like you have in your question), your question is hard to answer.

Comment: @Blender given that the user will be uploading relatively high quality images... how would it work? Is there a better approach?

Comment: @dandavis given that i have the image in base64 format in my app, how would i implement the B+W example?

Comment: you have to load the image it into a <canvas>, using drawImage from an <img> who's .src is a dataURL made from your base64 data. Then call getImageData on the canvas context to get a simple flattened array of rgba sub-pixel value. it sounds more complex than it is; look up a canvas image tutorial for details.

Comment: @methuselah: You'll have to define "high quality" and "closest match" first. Can you provide an example of a user-submitted picture? How do you measure "closeness"? The profile of the shoe? The pattern on it? The colors? All of these things are equally trivial for humans to reason about, but they're either simple or extremely difficult problems for computers.

Comment: @Blender an example of a user submitted photo is this: http://imgur.com/a/A0pLo. In terms of closeness, a general shape of the shoe will do... it doesnt have to be perfect.. it just needs to look similar in shape